# How to extract rows with highest number in one column but specific to categorical variables form other column in R?

Tags: r

So, let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 b= c(1,2,2,2,3,2,3,3))
```

How do I extract the rows with the highest number in each individual category of column `a`
so that I end up with a dataframe like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("A","A","B","C","C"),
                 b= c(2,2,3,3,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `slice_max()` from the dplyr package (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html);

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 b= c(1,2,2,2,3,2,3,3))

df1 <- data.frame(a = c("A","A","B","C","C"),
                  b= c(2,2,3,3,3))

df2 <- df %>%
  slice_max(b, by = a)

all.equal(df1, df2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>